# Rails select can't get both onchange and selected default to work at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using select for a drop down menu and I want it to update the view onchange and I want it to show the default selected value to be the value that was last selected. I can get one or the other to work but not both at the same time. here is my code.

```
<%= select("num", "xs1", a.map {|f| [f,f], {include_blank: true}, selected: params[:num], :onchange => "this.form.submit();") %>
```

With this code the onchange works but not the selected part. If I change the order and put onchange first the selected part works but not the onchange. Is there a way to write this to get both to work?

Comment: According to this example: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select#51-Demo-select-onchange-invoke-an-ajax- you should be including `selected: params[:num]` in the brackets with `include_blank: true`. Maybe that would work.

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't seem to work. I don't get a syntax error or anything it just doesn't do anything when I add it there.

Comment: it appears that it does work actually if I hard wire a sting into it `selected: "name"`. It's the 'params[:num]' part that does not work.

Comment: Is params[:num] always defined? It could be a `nil` case. What if you try `params[:num].to_s`?

Comment: Your right params[:num] does not persist after an option is selected and it goes back through the controller, so it comes back as nil. Instead I replaced it with `selected: @cards.first.xs1`. @cards gets set when it goes through the controller and I can get the name of the option I wanted it to show from the column in the model that the options were based on.

Comment: Glad that you could make it work. If you have figured this out you can post an answer yourself. That way anyone else stumbling across this problem can figure it out.